# Erroe using a extra project in my project

Tags: java, forms

In my code when I add a project to my library and I want to use it, it has ERROR that says

> "TextReader is not public in pack4.TextReader; cannot be accessed from
>   outside package"

But here is my code in pack4:

```
package pack4;

public class TextReader {

    private String path;

    TextReader (String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String[] readFile() throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numberOfLines = numberOfLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int counter = 0;
        for(counter = 0; counter < numberOfLines; counter++) {
            textData[counter] = bf.readLine();
        }

        bf.close();
        return textData;
    }

    public int numberOfLines() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int lineCounter = 0;
        while(bf.readLine() != null) {
            lineCounter++;
        }

        bf.close();
        return lineCounter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `TextReader` class as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your incomplete description, I'm guessing you should probably add "public" to constructor.